# I'm starting to use or learn c language

Tags: c

> Write a program that uses two dimensional of 256x8 to store 8 bit binary representation of each of the character of ASCII character set

I didn't understand this question properly. Should I have to use 2d array? And place 256 characters on them.. give me some advised or help me sort out to this problem

Comment: It is my understanding that you are supposed to have an array of 256 elements, in which each element itself is an array of 8 characters. Yes, this would be a 2D-array. In C, you would declare this as `char [256][8] arrays;`. If you want them to be null-terminated strings, then you also need room for the null terminator: `char [256][9] strings;`

Comment: It sounds like they want you to put each bit in a separate array element, so you need a 2d array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question asked you to store the binary representation of all ASCII characters in an array.

As every [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character is 8 bit long you need 8 places(ex. int or bool) for each 256 elements total 256*8 2D array.

You can declare the array as,

```
int codes[256][8];
```

Now for ASCII of 'a' is 97(dec) or 01100001(bin).

```
codes[96][0]=0;
codes[96][1]=1;
codes[96][2]=1;
codes[96][3]=0;
codes[96][4]=0;
codes[96][5]=0;
codes[96][6]=0;
codes[96][7]=1;
```

You can print the binary representation as,

```
for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    printf("%d",codes['a'][i]);
```

Comment: `printf("%d",codes['a'][i]);` isn't going to print the binary representation of `codes[96]` ;) 96 <> 97 ;)